# "On a course" vs "In a course" in American English

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, idiomatic-language, prepositional-phrases

In American English, what is the exact difference between

- a student/teacher being **on** or **in** a course

and what is the difference between

- a class/exam/subject etc. being **on** or **in** a course?

*Example sentences:*

> I am a student **in/on** the Math course.

> Are you one one of the teachers **on/in** this course?

> Are there going to be online classes **on/in** this course?

> I didn't learn a lot **on/in** this course.

> What is going to be taught **on/in** Ms. Johnson's course?

*Note:* *I want to know about the usage in American English because from what I see in previous topics on this on other forums, there is probably a difference between the usage in AE and BE in terms of on/in a course.*

Answer (score 1):

In the US, everything is **in a course**: the students, the teachers, the books, the content.

If something is **on a course** or simply **on course**, then it is heading in a specified direction. This is commonly said of ships and aircraft, but many will say it of automobiles or any other moving object.

Metaphorically, **on course** can mean that you are making the expected progress toward a goal, such as writing a book or building a house.

Comment: I'm a Brit, but I've lived in the US for over a decade so I feel I have a decent grasp of AE vs BE differences. As a result, I didn't buy this answer at first. However, I did some googling and to my surprise I found that Jeffrey is correct. Even past expressions like "been on/in a course" seem to be pretty much exclusively the "in" form in AE. To say that I have "been in a course" just sounds daft to my BE ears, but I found it, and not the "on" form on several US university sites. Whodathunk!

Comment: One exception I did find was where the notion of "sitting in" was also involved. I found several instances of _"... sit in **on** a course"_ and, for obvious reasons, _no_ instances of _"sit in **in** a course"_

Comment: @tkp As a native speaker of AmE, I think I would only ever say that I "have been in a course" to indicate something unusual, perhaps that I started a course but didn't finish. Otherwise I would say that I "have taken a course" or just that I "took a course."